# Strip out all formatting tags of excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

The author of the bottom code states that he uses the_excerpt_rss() because it "strips out all formatting tags". My question is do both codes below "strip out all formatting tags" ? What is the difference between the two codes below? Which would you suggest using?

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />

versus

<meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Without the contents of the `the_excerpt_rss()` function, one must assume that inside the function strips tags and echos the result...but I don't know what that function does...so I can't be 100% percent sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the_excerpt_rss() does *not* strip HTML tags, parses out links for numbered URL footnotes. In order for it to actually strip tags, you will have to pass 2 to the parameter $encode_html (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt_rss):

> $encode_html
>   (integer) Defines html tag filtering and special character (e.g. '&') encoding. Options are:
>   0 - (Default) Parses out links for numbered "url footnotes".
>   1 - Filters through the PHP function htmlspecialchars(), but also sets cut to 0, so is not recommended > when using the cut parameter.
>   2 - Strips html tags, and replaces '&' with HTML entity equivalent (&). This is the default when > using the cut parameter.

I would probably rely on the PHP strip_tags() anyway just because the_excerpt_rss() is intended for use in RSS feeds, so strip_tags() seems cleaner to me.